# Too many parts after spliting with regexes

Tags: regex, powershell, split

I'm trying to parse some logs using split and regexes in powershell

Here's my code :

```
$string = "Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code. Test 229: Passed Test 260: Failed. Error message: Status: Test case failed.  Steps: Navigate to: PurchReqTableListPage (purchreqpreparedbyme) Use the Quick Filter to find records. For example, filter on the Purchase requisition fION()</StackTrace> </Error>   Playback results: Tests: 2 Passed: 1 Failed: 1"

$string -Split '(Test (\d)+:)'
```

Result :

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Test 229:
9
 Passed
Test 260:
0
 Failed. Error message: Status: Test case failed.  Steps: Navigate to: PurchReqTableListPage (purchreqpreparedbyme) Use the Quick Filter to find records. For example, filter on the Purchase requisition fION()</StackTrace> </Error>   Playback results: Tests: 2 Passed: 1 Failed: 1
```

Expected result:

```
Starting ChromeDriver 78.0.3904.70Please protect ports used by ChromeDriver and related test frameworks to prevent access by malicious code.
Test 229:
 Passed
Test 260:
 Failed. Error message: Status: Test case failed.  Steps: Navigate to: PurchReqTableListPage (purchreqpreparedbyme) Use the Quick Filter to find records. For example, filter on the Purchase requisition fION()</StackTrace> </Error>   Playback results: Tests: 2 Passed: 1 Failed: 1
```

On this site : https://regexr.com/3c0lf I tried this regex and the groups captured were : `Test 260:` and `Test 229:` (which is exactly what I want)

I do not understand where the `0` and the `9` comes from.

Thanks a lot

Comment: Those are the last digits of the number.  0 from 260 and 9 from 229.  Try: `$string -Split '(Test \d+:)'`

Comment: @RobertMcKee thanks a lot, it's working, would you mind posting it as an answer and just explaining why my regex was catching the one digit group as well ? (so I can accept it)

Comment: Done, but your link is pointing to the wrong regexr from what I can tell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those are the last digits of the number. 0 from 26*0* and 9 from 22*9*.
You are seeing those because you've created an additional capturing group by putting parentheses around the digits.  Just remove them like so:

```
$string -Split '(Test \d+:)
```

You probably don't even need those parentheses either, leaving just

```
$string -Split 'Test \d+:
```

Comment: The parenthesis allow me to keep the matched groups in the split result

Comment: Ah... You are looking for the atomic positive look behind, which will do the same thing without abusing the capturing group(s).

Comment: I will google that and look into it, thanks for the hint

Comment: try this pattern: `(?<=Test \d+:)`

Comment: Hum,no, the format of my logs are ' [initializing text] [ Test xxx:] [result of the test] [error message if test failed] [Test xxx:] [result of the test] [error message if test failed] [Tests: N Passed: X Failed: Y]' (the [] is the way i'd like to split)